# Object get accessor not returning intended value

Tags: javascript

I'm learning OO JS right now and I'm having trouble wrapping my head around why this doesn't work:

```
var dog = {

    name: {

        value: 'PENNY',

        get: function() {
            return this.name; // returns [object Object]
        }
    }
};

alert(dog.name);
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong but I don't know what. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You lost context basically, but why `this.name` and not `this.value`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of the `name` property on dog is an object that has a `get()` method.  If you change the code to:

```
var dog = {

    name: {

        value: 'PENNY',

        get: function() {
            return this.value; // Change to 'value'.  returns 'PENNY'
        }
    }
};

alert(dog.name.get()); // Change to call the get() method on the name object
```

You will get the correct name out.  But you probably want the `name` function to be automatically called when reading the property.  In that case you can change it to:

```
var dog = {

    value: 'PENNY',

    get name() {
        return this.value; // returns 'PENNY'
    }

};

alert(dog.name);
```

Which uses the getter syntax to define a property called `name` that will call the specified function when reading the property.

Comment: You're right, the second example is probably what the OP is looking for (at least that's what I think, since "accessor" is mentioned).

Comment: Kudos for actually answering the OP's question =)  I got a little off track.  Still, I recommend looking into `console.log()` as a better way to debug and understand js.

Answer (score 2):

you should use `console.log(dog.name)` to inspect the object.

`Alert`, as you have just found, is a very clumsy way to debug Javascript.  What you are seeing in the alert box is the result of taking the name object's `toString` method.  In many Javascript implementations, `toString` returns "`[object Object]`" as a way of printing an object's "value"

In this case, you are indirectly getting `dog.name.toString()` and since name is an object, it prints `[object Object]`.

I have included a JSFiddle with your code, followed by a console.log statement. http://jsfiddle.net/us9TL/ if you open the developer tools, and run the javascript, you can compare the two outputs of the same object.

in order to view the output of `console.log` you need to open your browser's Developer tools.

Instructions for opening developer tools:
For Chrome: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/
For Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to do what I think you're trying to do, your syntax is incorrect. Try this:

```
var dog = {

    name: {

        _val: 'PENNY',

        get value() {
            return this._val; // returns 'PENNY'
        }
    }
};

console.log(dog.name.value);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9Jq9h/

Answer (score 0):

Why not...?

```
var dog = {
    name : 'PENNY',

    get: function() {
        return this.name;
    }
};
```

What happened to you is that you defined name as `name : {}`, where `{}` is the notation for an Object. That object has another value called `value` which is a string. Using your logic, you should access it like `this.value` (being `this` an identifier for the `name` object and not the `dog` object, due to scopes).